# Tiny (unreadable) apostrophes and double quotes on some web pages

Tags: firefox, fonts, rendering

I'm using the latest firefox (Quantum 61.0) on a 4K display on FreeBSD. Certain web pages are rendered incorrectly, in particular there's a problem with apostrophes and double quotes being so tiny as to be unreadable. One page this happens is this [European Union](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/news/en/press-room/20180712IPR07806/statement-by-the-brexit-steering-group-on-uk-government-white-paper) page.

Search for "Parliament's". This is a screenshot how it is rendered on Firefox.
[image]

Magnified with xmag:

[image]

If I had to guess, it looks like the regular font is rendered in 36 pixel height, while the apostrophe is about 12 pixels tall, but uses the same baseline.

I'm using some non-standard values in about:config to have text readable on a 4K display, in particular `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx: 2.0` (default: 1.0) and
`layout.css.dpi: 150;` (default: -1).

Can anyone reproduce this? How can I have proper rendering of apostrophes and quotes?

**EDIT**
The apostrophe is correctly rendered when I increase the font size (via FF Ctrl-+) to 140% or above. At these sizes, the font is also anti-aliased instead of rasterized as demonstrated in this xmag close-up:

[image]

Comment: Use ctrl and (+-) to adjust typeface size within firefox, and check what main display font firefox is using. I may be teaching you to suck eggs here :)

Comment: try copy pasting them into word then put your cursor to its right and do ALT-X  to see its character code, that will be some info that may help in your investigations

Comment: @JohnnyVegas When I increase the font size to 140%, the proper size apostrophe is used. Any size below is rendered incorrectly.

Comment: @barlop It's a 3 byte Unicode code point with values (octal)  342 200 231.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas In the preferences the default font is serif, Deja Vu Sans, size 18. The sans serif font is Bitstream Charter.

Comment: What is the windows/linux default text size set to -and what is your screen resolution?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas The screen resolution is 4096x2160 (true 4k). The default font size in the preferences is 18, which, with `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx: 2.0` would be a 36 monitor pixel default font.

Comment: Sounds like the OS can't quite display 4k desktops properly - What does the screen look like when you set it to 1920x1080?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas How would I start X11 with a different resolution than the native one of the monitor? I doubt the OS is at fault. A Unix kernel (FreeBSD here) does not do font rendering. To me it looks like the font rendering subsystem of FF switches modes from a b&w raster with unscaled glyphs for certain UTF-8 characters to proper vector font with anti-aliasing at 140%.

Comment: Does the same happen in chromium?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas No, chrome renders the apostrophes properly. On FF I reset the layout.css parameters to their defaults, still the same problem. So it must be a FF-specific rendering bug.

Comment: I think this might relate to the font in question. The add-on [Font Finder (revived)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-inspect/) can find the actual font being used and all properties, which might help analyze the problem.

Comment: @harrymc A valuable hint! I found that the problem is with pages requesting "Helvetica". Firefox for some reason falls back to rendering "System Default". If in the FF preferences I deselect "Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of your selections above" I can force e.g. Arial or Calibri and rendering is fine at all sizes. When I force Helvetica, the problem appears. So it seems like I don't have a proper Helvetica font for FF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your findings, the Helvetica font is the problem.

Firefox does not distinguish between Helvetica variants and chooses almost at random a variant that seems to fit the specs.
For example, I have heard of such problems when the Helvetica Neue font is installed
and "takes over" the display.

You might look for some Helvetica font variants that you never use and uninstall them.

Another solution might be to force the replacement of Helvetica by Arial, as follows.

- Go to your Firefox profile directory
- Create a directory called `chrome` and a text file inside that directory called `userContent.css`, and add the following line to the file:

  ```
  @font-face { font-family: 'helvetica'; src: local('Arial'); }
  ```

  If you have other installed variants of helvetica, add such lines for each one,
  for example :

  ```
  @font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; src: local('Arial'); }
  ```
- Restart Firefox.

---

I draw attention to the Firefox add-on that was instrumental in analyzing
the problem :
[Font Finder (revived)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/font-inspect/).

> "Font Finder (revived)" is WebExtension implementation of the XUL
>   "FontFinder". This extension is created for designers, developers and
>   typographers. It allows a user to analyze the font information of any
>   element on a page, copy any piece(s) of that information to the
>   clipboard.